# Using "require_once" in my plugin breaks Media Library access from Dashboard

Tags: media-library

I am developing a plugin in Windows 10 UwAmp wordpress environment, with "Twenty Twenty One" theme. PHP 8.0.28, mysql 5.7.11, WP 6.2.2.

At present my plugin file is as follows:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Miscellaneous SXF functions for asechka.com
     * Description: Site specific code changes for asechka.com
     */
    
    require_once 'lib/media-lib-test.php';
```

My 'lib/media-lib-test.php' is as follows:

```
    <?php
    // echo '<h3>_________________________________media-lib-test.php: before [if]</h3>';
    if ( !function_exists( 'sxf_dummy_function' ) ) :
    /**
     *
    */
    // echo '<h3>_________________________________media-lib-test.php: inside [if]</h3>';
    function sxf_dummy_function() { return;}
    endif;
```

The "require_once" finds the 'lib/media-lib-test.php' Ok - I tested it using the "echo" in the 'lib/media-lib-test.php'.

With these two files I am having two problems (at least).

1. When I try to display Media Library form Dashboard (the left sidebar in Admin), the wheel keeps turning, but nothing displays, not a single thumbnail.
2. When I bring up "Site Health" -> Info -> Directories and Sizes", the sizes do not show, instead the message "Loading..." keeps displaying. It is so for all directories on this screen ("upload", "themes", "plugins", "database", etc.)

But, if as soon as I comment out the "require_once" command, Media Library and "Site Health" both work just fine, as expected.

My guess that there is something wrong with JavaScripts behind Media Library and Site Health, but I don't know how to debug it.

Please advise.

Comment: Turned out both the plugin file and  'lib/media-lib-test.php' file had three BOM bytes at the beginning of the file "ef bb bf" (they show only in HEX view of the files). WP outputs those in the header which messes up the HTML and JavaScript. When I removed those, both problems got corrected. I'm closing my question now.